# fatal error LNK1168: cannot open bin\llvm-tblgen.exe for writing

Tags: windows, visual-studio

I am frequently facing intermittent build issues on my windows build host. I am using cmake with Ninja build generator.

`bin\llvm-tblgen.exe` file is creating successfully. But it fails to write. i make sure to add build directories to exclusion list of security scan.

```
/MANIFESTFILE:utils\TableGen\CMakeFiles\llvm-tblgen.dir/intermediate.manifest utils\TableGen\CMakeFiles\llvm-tblgen.dir/manifest.res" failed (exit code 1168) with the following output:
LINK : fatal error LNK1168: cannot open bin\llvm-tblgen.exe for writing
```

As per my search over Microsoft official forums, Issue might occur for 2 reasons

1. when there is one process already locking the .exe file and other process tries to access it
2. if we are running parallel build.
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/tool-errors/linker-tools-error-lnk1168?view=msvc-170

Need suggestions here to debug. Thanks!